# What match="/" actually returns?

Tags: xslt

What exactly does match="/" returns if we assume we have XML shown below?
As far as I can tell it returns some imaginary top level node which has `<people>` element as its child. What is the type of this node among those 7 types of nodes: 
element, attribute, text, namespace, processing-instruction, comment, document nodes

test.xml

```
<people>

  <person>
    <name> John </name>
    <age>  50   </age>
  </person>

</people>
```

Comment: Where did you get your list of "7 types of nodes"?

Comment: From the ultimate www reference http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_nodes.asp

Comment: "*the ultimate www reference*" I hope you are joking.

Comment: Yeah. It is reallty lacking. It semas like you can use it to learn things fast but then you find out that it lacks data, or that data is wrong or whatever. I have a feeling as if people who make those tutorials aren't really using techonogly they are descibing. I was hoping that it will be different with XSLT. I was wrong.

Comment: It's a tutorial. It's good to get you up and running with the most basic tasks. It does not provide theoretical background and some of the concepts are oversimplified to the point of being wrong. -- OTOH, the formal specifications are not exactly a model of clarity either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use this XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- comment1 -->
<?pi1?>
<!-- comment2 -->
<people>
  <person>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>50</age>
  </person>
</people>
<!-- comment3 -->
<?pi2?>
<!-- comment4 -->
```

And let's create a XSLT file that informs us about the top level structure of the processed XML file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <nodes><xsl:apply-templates/></nodes>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment()">
        <node>comment()</node>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
        <node>processing-instruction()</node>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <node>text()</node>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <node>node()</node>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We obtain this:

```
<nodes>
  <node>comment()</node>
  <node>processing-instruction()</node>
  <node>comment()</node>
  <node>node()</node>
  <node>comment()</node>
  <node>processing-instruction()</node>
  <node>comment()</node>
</nodes>
```

In other words: The children of the root node could be any number of comments and processing instructions, and a single root element. There could be no text and no attribute at this level.

Answer (score 0):

In **XPath**:

> / selects the document root (which is always the parent of the
>   document element)

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths

In **XSLT**:

> / matches the root node

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#patterns

For the definition of *root node* you [must refer to the XPath data model](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#data-model), which defines it as:

> The root node is the root of the tree. A root node does not occur
>   except as the root of the tree. The element node for the document
>   element is a child of the root node. The root node also has as
>   children processing instruction and comment nodes for processing
>   instructions and comments that occur in the prolog and after the end
>   of the document element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node

In **XML** the root node is formally defined as:

> The document entity serves as the root of the entity tree and a
>   starting-point for an XML processor.

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-docent

Comment: Thanks everyone so much for the help. Official documentation is to complicated for me but I have found this http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/root.html that tries to explain root node in normal English.

Answer (score 0):

A match pattern does not 'return' anything. You apply a pattern to a node and it either matches that node or it does not match. In the case of the pattern "/", it matches a node if and only if the node is a document node.

(Note: there is some variation of terminology between specs here. XPath 2.0 and DOM both talk of "document nodes", and they use the term essentially in the same way. XPath 1.0 had the same concept, but called it a "root node". But some specifications, including the XML specification itself, use the term "root" to describe the outermost element.)

A document node is imaginary only in the sense that there is no tangible markup corresponding to the node. But if you're thinking that markup is real and nodes are imaginary, then you're not really thinking XSLT. From an XSLT perspective, trees are real, they are the only thing you interact with.