# xslt: Is there any way to reference the root node?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there any way to get access to the ROOT node from within another context?

The example above is just to show my intention. Getting access to ROOT_NODE without using '../../..' since changes in xml could break that type of selector.

**XSLT**

```
<div class="column">
  <xsl:for-each select="languages/server/elem">
    <!-- Context is ELEM node -->
    <div>
      <!-- How can I get access to the ROOT_NODE ?-->
      <span class="text"><xsl:value-of select="ROOT_NODE/@title"/></span>
      <!-- Print ELEM text -->
      <span class="text"><xsl:value-of select="current()"/></span>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you consider a "root node" and in particular not what you consider "the root node" if you talk about different contexts (documents?) but `/` selects the root node/document node of the context node and `/*` the root element of the context node.

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985786/about-root-node-in-xslt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression "`/`" selects the document node at the root of the tree containing the context node. (All trees in 1.0 are rooted at document nodes.)

In XSLT 2.0, `root()` selects the root of the tree containing the context node whether or not the root is a document node.

To get the root of the principal source document even when the context node is a node in a different tree, bind a global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="principal-root" select="/"/>
```

which you can refer to anywhere as `$principal-root`.

Oh, and as Mads Hansen points out, if by "root node" you actually mean the outermost element node, as distinct from the document node, then you would typically use "`/*`".

Answer (score 2):

The [**root node**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#root-node) is the root of the XML tree, and is the space above the document element. Since an XML document could also have comments and processing instructions as top-level nodes, it gives you the ability to select them as well.

http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#location-paths

> / selects the document root (which is always the parent of the document element)

It sounds as if you want to reference the ["root element", also known as the "document element"](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed), so that you can get the value of it's `@title`.

You can select that with the following XPath:

```
/*/@title
```